# simple security rule to read a given document

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am getting simulated read denied for accessing a simple collection

```
Data Model:
/users/$userId/
```

This is a simple collection, with no sub-collection.

In my simulator I am doing a get on a single document

```
/databases/users/documents/0011476476904
```

With below authentication payload

```
{
  "uid": "0011476476904",
  "token": {
    "sub": "0011476476904",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "phone_number": "",
    "name": "",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a simple rule to allow read if auth.uid matches userId but I am still getting  simulation rule denied

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/users/documents/{userId} {

      allow read, write: if userId == request.auth.uid;

  }
}
```

is there anything wrong in the way I have set the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single `users` collection, the way you should modelize/define your security rules is the following:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'users' collection
    match /users/{userId} {
         allow read, write: if userId == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) for more details. Also, it's worth watching the video embedded in this doc [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: Thanks! I still am getting a simulation denied error with this.

Comment: Probably because you use `/databases/users/documents/0011476476904`in the simulator. You should use `/databases/users/0011476476904`.

Comment: Ah ok. But when I use /databases/users/0011476476904 it complains that "Path must be document-level"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you just have to use `users/0011476476904` without `databases`. As you can see in the simulator under the Location title, the "base path" is already considered by the simulator (`/databases/(default)/documents`)

Comment: thank you that works. I did a very noob mistake on my end . thanks for pointing